# Reattaching an entity to lazy load a collection (JPA/Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

Can anyone help me with a JPA issue that I thought would have been simple.  I'm trying to write a general-purpose lazy load manager in my JPA persistence framework, so layers higher up the application stack can access lazy-loaded data without having to deal with the specifics.

I have a lazy load manager:

```
public class JpaLazyLoader extends AbstractJpaDAO<Void> implements LazyLoader
{

  public JpaLazyLoader()
  {
    super( void.class ); 
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly=true)
  public <T,E> T get( ILazyGetter<T,E> p_getter ) throws Exception {
    // reattach the object to the session

    E l_entity = getEntityManager().merge( p_getter.getEntity() );

    // return the getter data
    return p_getter.get( l_entity );
  }
}
```

The lazy getter is like this:

```
public interface ILazyGetter<T,E> extends Serializable
{
  public E getEntity();
  public T get( E p_entity ) throws Exception;
}
```

And the idea is that it would be used like this:

```
          return m_lazyLoader.get( new ILazyGetter<Collection<Child>, Parent>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public Parent getEntity() {
              return getValue(); // get the parent object from somewhere
            }

            public Collection<Child> get( Parent p_entity ) throws Exception {
              // children are a lazy-loaded Set<Child>
              return p_entity.getChildren();
            }
          } );
```

The annotations in Parent are like this:

```
@Entity(name="parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  ....

  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Long id;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable
  (
      name="parent_child_associations",
      joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id") },
      inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true) }
  )
  protected Set<Child> children;
```

}

The parent object was loaded in a different transaction and then detached.  I hoped it would be a trivial thing to reattach the parent to another session (within the @transactional bit) but I can't get it to work.  I've tried optimistic/pessimistic/none locking before and after the merge but none seem to work.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: test.Parent.children, could not initialize proxy - no Session
 at     org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
 at     org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
 at     org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
 at     org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
 at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
```

Is this just the wrong way to go about things?  If so, what is the 'correct' way?  If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Apparently you successfully do fetch the collection, but is it initialized? Seems you return the unopened bag and when you try to iterate over that bag, it will try open it, giving you the exception.
Is there a open session when you iterate over the collection? If so, can you try call Hibernate.initialize()?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly where I was going wrong. - I didn't want to tie my JPA to Hibernate, so instead I ensure the collection is initialised.  See comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK well thanks to Andre I've got it working.

I simply hadn't initialised the collection object, instead I was just calling parent.getChildren(), which only returned the proxy object rather than forcing the fetch.

The updated get method is below for anyone who has a similar need:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public <T,E> T get( ILazyGetter<T,E> p_getter ) throws Exception {
  // reattach the object to the session    
  E l_entity = getEntityManager().merge( p_getter.getEntity() );

  T l_lazyData = p_getter.get( l_entity );

  // Just getting the data doesn't necessarily initialize it - 
  // explicitly initialize it depending on the data type.
  intializeEntity( l_lazyData );

  // return the getter data
  return l_lazyData;
}

/**
 * Attempt to initialize the entity so it is fully lazy loaded while in the transaction
 * @param p_entity
 */
protected void intializeEntity( Object p_entity ) {
  if( p_entity != null && p_entity instanceof Collection ) {
    Collection<?> l_entity = (Collection<?>)p_entity;
    l_entity.size(); // force the collection to load
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, would you kindly mark this as a chosen answer :-)